# Как просмотреть стандартные библиотеки в VS 2010 Expres?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, visual-studio

Для выполения задачи в С++ мне нужно подключить стандартную библиотеку с математическими операторами.
**Вопрос в следующем:**
 1. Имя библиотеки?
 2. Как ее просмотреть?
 3. Как понять что за что отвечает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то Visual Studio тут не при чем.
Стандартная библиотека является неотъемлемой частью языка C++, поэтому любой компилятор языка С++ должен предоставлять доступ к стандартной библиотеке. 
В частности для использования математической библиотеки следует подключить файл cmath.
Документацию можно прочитать по [ссылке](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/).  Пример использования:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const double PI = 3.14159265;
    std::cout << "sin of 45 degrees equals to " << std::sin(PI / 4) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что и другие стандартные библиотеки там можно найти.
А чтобы понять что к чему - нужно просто знание английского или хотя-бы он-лайн переводчик. 
Большое спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

в vs она кажется называется "math.h"